# Proving the almost sure convergence of $Y_n := \min(\lfloor{2^nX}\rfloor/2^n, n)$ to $X$.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I refer to Q17 of Chapter 1, Second Course in Probability, Sheldon Ross. The question is as follows:

> Given a nonnegative random variable $X$ define the sequence of random variables $Y_n = \min(\lfloor 2^nX \rfloor/2^n,n)$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the integer portion of $x$. Show that $Y_n \uparrow X$ and $E[X] = \lim_{n} E[Y_n]$.

It is rather clear that we need to invoke Monotone Convergence Theorem here. To prove the monotonicity of $Y_n$, I have established the following lemmas:

> **Lemma 0**: Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\lfloor{x}\rfloor + \lfloor{y}\rfloor \leq \lfloor{x + y}\rfloor \leq \lfloor{x}\rfloor + \lfloor{y}\rfloor + 1$.

This is trivial and can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties).

> **Lemma 1**: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\min(\lfloor 2^nx \rfloor/2^n,n) \leq \min(\lfloor 2^{n+1}x \rfloor/2^{n+1},n+1)$.

I'll omit the proof for this as it is rather long and tedious. The main idea is to consider two cases: $\lfloor 2^{n+1}x \rfloor/2^{n+1} \leq n + 1$ and $\lfloor 2^{n+1}x \rfloor/2^{n+1} > n + 1$. This suffices to show the monotonicity of $Y_n$.

> **Lemma 2**: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\lfloor{2^nx}\rfloor/2^n \leq n$, then $\lfloor{2^{n+1}x}\rfloor/2^{n+1} \leq n+1$.

This is also rather straightforward to prove, mainly using Lemma 0. This shows that to prove almost sure convergence, it suffices to show that $\lfloor{2^nX}\rfloor/2^n \leq n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. This is because one can check that $\left|X - \lfloor{2^nX}\rfloor/2^n\right| \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$, so we can simply tend $n$ to infinity.

As you may see by now, my main difficulty in this question is purely the proving of almost convergence. Most questions I found online which require us to prove almost sure convergence usually give the specific distribution of $X$ (e.g. uniform, gamma, etc.), but since here $X$ can follow any distribution (as long as it remains nonnegative) I have no idea on how I should proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any real number $x$ we have $x-\frac 1 {2^{n}} <\frac {[2^{n}x]} {2^{n}} \leq x$.  Hence $\frac {[2^{n}x]} {2^{n}} \to x$ as $n \to \infty$. It follows that $\frac {[2^{n}X(\omega)]} {2^{n}}\to X(\omega)$ for every $\omega$. This also implies that $Y_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ for every $\omega$.

Comment: I can see this, but $Y_n$ is not simply $\lfloor{2^nx}\rfloor/2^n$ but rather $\min(\lfloor{2^nx}\rfloor/2^n, n)$. How can I be certain that $Y_n$ converges just like $\lfloor{2^nx}\rfloor/2^n$?

Comment: @ClementYung If $a_n \to a$ then $\min \{a_n, n\} \to1$. This is because $a_n <a+1<n$ whenever $n$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Okay, this is what I understand now: for every $\omega$, we have that $Y_n(\omega)$ is a finite number, and is bounded from above by $X(\omega)$. As a result, such an $n$ must exist. Since this holds for every $\omega$, $Y_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ so by definition $Y_n \to X$ almost surely. Am I correct?

Comment: @ClementYung Right. The main point is a.s. convergence does not require any probability theory here. You don't have to work with distribution functions at all.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\omega\in\Omega$.

We have: $$\lfloor2^nX(\omega)\rfloor/2^n\leq 2^nX(\omega)/2^n=X(\omega)$$ so that for $n$ large enough (i.e. $X(\omega)<n$)  we find:$$Y_n=\min(\lfloor2^nX(\omega)\rfloor/2^n,n)=\lfloor2^nX(\omega)\rfloor/2^n$$hence:$$X(\omega)-2^{-n}<Y_n(\omega)\leq X(\omega)$$
implying that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n(\omega)=X(\omega)$$

This for every $\omega\in\Omega$.